# How to parse an string array as JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, infusionsoft

I'm having the hardest time getting this string to be parseable. It may seem like a simple task, but it's driving me crazy. Infusionsoft returns this as their rest hook payload so I can't change the way it's recieved.

`JSON.parse()` doesn't work and I can't work with it as an object literal since the timestamp has no quotes. Is there a method or way I've just failed to see to parse this so I can easily get each `id` with a for loop as an example?

`[{id:1049105, api_url:'', timestamp: 2017-07-12T00:34:36.000Z},{id:993221, api_url:'', timestamp: 2017-07-12T00:34:18.000Z}]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not valid JSON at all, the properties should all have quotes around them to be valid.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the whole thing? Could you be a little bit more clear?

Comment: i get the feeling that you are getting valid JSON from the API, but that it is already parsed. For instance if you are using `jQuery.ajax` with `json` data type specified to send the request to the server. In which case you may have pasted the log output of your parsed object in your question. If that happens to be the case, then you don't need `JSON.parse()` at all.If this is not the case, I suggest pasting a code sample to make it easier to see what you are doing.

Comment: @Marconius I'm pretty sure it's coming in as a string and not parsed JSON. When the webhook comes in, the initial payload is parsed as JSON with bodyparser and I get this payload: `{ event_key: 'contact.edit', 
object_type: 'contact', 
object_key: '[{id:1057781, api_url:\'\', timestamp: 2017-07-11T19:24:41.000Z},{id:1035169, api_url:\'\', timestamp: 2017-07-11T19:23:56.000Z}]', 
api_url: '' }`

As you can see the `object_key` is represented as a string. I've tried just parsing that part with JSON.parse but it kicks back an error.

Answer (score 0):

With some string manipulation and iterating over the string parts we can parse this response into an Array of valid JS objects.

I've run the code below and I get back an array of JS Objects that map to each "object" in the array string. It will also convert the invalid timestamp value to a JS Date Object.

```
let args = "[{id:1049105, api_url:'', timestamp: 2017-07-12T00:34:36.000Z},{id:993221, api_url:'', timestamp: 2017-07-12T00:34:18.000Z}]"

let splitArgs = args.split('},')
// Create an Array of parsed Objects
let objs = splitArgs.map(arg => {
    // remove whitespace
    let cleanArg = arg.trim()

    // Remove enclosing [ { } ] characters
    if (arg.startsWith('[')) {
        cleanArg = cleanArg.substr(1, arg.length)
    }
    if (cleanArg.startsWith('{')) {
        cleanArg = cleanArg.substr(1, arg.length)
    }
    if (cleanArg.endsWith(']')) {
        cleanArg = cleanArg.substr(0, arg.length - 1)
    }
    if (cleanArg.endsWith('}')) {
        cleanArg = cleanArg.substr(0, arg.length - 1)
    }

    // Remove any quotations and then split each of the properties out  
    let props = cleanArg.replace(/[\']+/, '').split(',')

    // For each prop, get the value and assign it to the new object
    // that will be returned by reduce()
    return props.reduce((obj, prop) => {
        let splitIndex = prop.indexOf(':')
        let key = prop.substr(0, splitIndex)
        let val = prop.substr(splitIndex + 1, prop.length)

        if (key.toLowerCase() === 'timestamp') {
            obj[key] = (new Date(val))
        } else {
            obj[key] = val
        }
        return obj
    }, {})
})

console.log(objs.map(obj => { return obj.id })) // [1049105, 993221]
```

Comment: @BritGwaltney have you checked out my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

The dates are in ISO format, so you can use a couple regexes to preprocess the string to JSON

```
string = "[...]"; 
string.replace(/(\d{4}-\d_2+-\d{2} ... /g, '"$1"'); // enclose dates in quotes
string.replace(/'/g, '"'); // replace single quotes with double quotes
string.replace(/id/g, '"id"'); // enclose id in double quotes
// repeat for api_url and timestamp

data = JSON.parse(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the writer of [scanf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scanf), would you like try this:

```
const {sscanf} = require('scanf');

let str = `[{id:1049105, api_url:'', timestamp: 2017-07-12T00:34:36.000Z},{id:993221, api_url:'', timestamp: 2017-07-12T00:34:18.000Z}]`;
let chunks = str.split('},{');

for (let chunk of chunks) {
  let obj = sscanf(chunk, "id:%d, api_url:%s, timestamp: %s}", 'id', 'api_url', 'timestamp')
  console.log(obj);
}

/*
{ id: 1049105,
  api_url: '\'\'',
  timestamp: '2017-07-12T00:34:36.000Z' }
{ id: 993221,
  api_url: '\'\'',
  timestamp: '2017-07-12T00:34:18.000Z' }
*/
```

There may by some problem with usage or BUG, you can submit [issue](https://github.com/Lellansin/node-scanf/issues) for more.